# convert strings from mixed to upper case in windows batch scripting

Tags: windows, scripting, strings

Is there a way to convert strings from mixed to upper case in windows batch scripting?

I am writing a batch file to create certain objects and grant user groups access to them. That is, I should issue commands like

```
cas caslibs create path --name CAS_HRCOCKPIT --path /sas/data/projects/HRCOCKPIT /
cas caslibs add-control --name CAS_HRCOCKPIT --group GSSASELA-DEVHRCockpitUsers --grant read
cas caslibs add-control --name CAS_HRCOCKPIT --group GSSASELA-DEVHRCockpitAdmins --grant modify
```

The objects should be in upper case, but the user groups are not. How do I converts a string like `HRCockpit` into `HRCOCKPIT`?

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure I understand your question 100%. 
You seem to be asking how to convert (the value of) a variable
in a Windows batch file from mixed to all upper case. 
If so, the Super User question [How to make uppercase all files and folder
on a directory?](https://superuser.com/q/918404/150988), by [seçkin bilgiç](https://superuser.com/users/443910/se%c3%a7kin-bilgi%c3%a7), contains an answer. 
Assuming that your variable is called `obj`
(i.e., you have done `set obj=Cockpit`), do

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
     ︙
for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    set "obj=!obj:%%A=%%A!"
)
```

This uses the `%variable:old=new%` syntax
for doing a substitution in a variable value. 
For example, if we do `set animal=cow`, then `%animal:ow=at%` yields `cat`. 
A useful feature of this is that the match for the old string
is case-insensitive, but the replacement is case-preserving;
so `%animal:OW=AT%` yields `cAT`. 
Similarly, if `obj=Cockpit`, then `%obj:T=T%` yields `CockpiT`,
and so we can use this to replace a letter
with the upper case version of itself.

We loop through the alphabet, getting the effect of

```
    set "obj=%obj:A=A%"
    set "obj=%obj:B=B%"
    set "obj=%obj:C=C%"
     ︙
```

without having to do all 26 statements.

But variables behave strangely in loops in batch files. 
That’s why we have `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`,
and why we use `!...!` rather than `%...%` in the assignment in the loop.

Comment: It's worked. Nice solution.